# Oracle 11g database startup automation on Fedora 15

Tags: fedora, boot, oracle-database

I successfully installed Oracle 11g on a Fedora 15 system using [this](http://iamsys.wordpress.com/2010/11/08/oracle-11gr2-on-fedora-14/) guide. Unfortunately, unlike when I'm using Windows, it seems I need to restart the database every single time I reboot my machine (it's a development machine, not a server).

I'm not sure this is the intended behavior or if I messed up something while installing the database.

Anyway, every single I reboot the machine I need to:

- Use `su` to change the current user to the `oracle` user.
- Use `sqplus` to startup the database.

Like this:

```
(oracle@machine)$ sqplus / as sysdba
SQL> startup
SQL> (Ctrl+D)
```

- Then I need to start the listener using `lsnrctl`.

Once more:

```
(oracle@machine)$ lsnrctl start
```

- And now the Enterprise Manager should also be started.

At least:

```
(oracle@machine)$ emctl start dbconsole
```

I've taken those instructions from [here](http://setijoagus.wordpress.com/2008/11/07/oracle-11g-starting-the-oracle-enterprise-manager-console/).

I'm sorry if this quite noobish, I usually have a DBA or a sysadmin to setup an environment for me but I'm doing this at home, where I have no help (maybe I'm becoming quite spoiled as a developer :)).

I wonder if it's possible to automate this on Fedora 15 using a shell script. After automating, I'd like to hook this on the init system, so it's performed every time I start the machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found an answer on [this](http://www.talk2melbin.com/complete-installation-of-oracle-on-linux-machine-centos-5-3/) guide on how to install Oracle 11g on CentOS 5.3. I did some minor tweaking on the init script. For the sake of completeness, I'll add steps here:

- Edit `/etc/oratab` and change the last `N` on the configuration file to an `Y`.

Like this:

```
orcl:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1:N
```

To this:

```
orcl:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1:Y
```

- Create the script `/etc/init.d/dbora`.

It should have this contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
# chkconfig: 345 99 10
# description: Oracle auto start-stop script.
#
# Set ORA_HOME to be equivalent to the $ORACLE_HOME
# from which you wish to execute dbstart and dbshut;
#
# Set ORA_OWNER to the user id of the owner of the
# Oracle database in ORA_HOME.

ORA_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1
ORA_OWNER=oracle

if [ ! -f $ORA_HOME/bin/dbstart ]
then
        echo "Oracle startup: cannot start"
        exit
fi

case "$1" in

'start')

# Start the Oracle databases:
# The following command assumes that the oracle login
# will not prompt the user for any values

su - $ORA_OWNER -c "$ORA_HOME/bin/emctl start dbconsole"
su - $ORA_OWNER -c "$ORA_HOME/bin/lsnrctl start"
su - $ORA_OWNER -c "$ORA_HOME/bin/dbstart $ORA_HOME"
;;

'stop')

# Stop the Oracle databases:
# The following command assumes that the oracle login
# will not prompt the user for any values

su - $ORA_OWNER -c "$ORA_HOME/bin/emctl stop dbconsole"
su - $ORA_OWNER -c "$ORA_HOME/bin/lsnrctl stop"
su - $ORA_OWNER -c "$ORA_HOME/bin/dbshut $ORA_HOME"
;;

esac
```

- Then change the script permission.

Like this:

```
chmod 750 /etc/init.d/dbora
```

- Add it to chkconfig

Like this:

```
chkconfig --level 345 dbora on
```

Test it with `/etc/init.d/dbora start` and `/etc/init.d/dbora stop`. Be sure to have the correct path on the `dbora` script.

Answer (score 1):

I think `lsnrctl start` is already included in the `dbstart` script.